# What is wrong with this do...while loop C#?

Tags: c#, while-loop, char, do-while

I wrote this code to get a set of characters until a specific character was read. I know there's a better way but just of curiosity.
It didn't work. The loop continued endlessly.
Why is this ???

```
foreach (char myChar in monthYear)
{
    do
    {
        whichMonth = whichMonth + myChar;
    } while (myChar.ToString() == "-");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what you are telling the compiler to do...

```
foreach (char myChar in monthYear)
{

    do  // Execute this piece of code
    {
        whichMonth = whichMonth + myChar;
    } while (myChar.ToString() == "-"); // While myChar is '-'

    // Here, the foreach loop moves to the next character
}
```

So, given the string `02-2013`, here is the execution path of your code.

- **`foreach` character in my `monthYear`**

  - `myChar = '0'`
  - **`do`**

    - `whichMonth = whichMonth + '0'`
    - **`while(myChar == '-')`** *Is `false`, exit `while` loop*
  - `myChar = '2'`
  - **`do`**

    - `whichMonth = whichMonth + '2'`
    - **`while(myChar == '-')`** *Is `false`, exit `while` loop*
  - `myChar = '-'`
  - **`do`**

    - `whichMonth = whichMonth + '-'`
    - **`while(myChar == '-')`** *Is `true`, continue `while` loop*
    - `whichMonth = whichMonth + '-'`
    - **`while(myChar == '-')`** *Is `true`, continue `while` loop*
    - `whichMonth = whichMonth + '-'`
    - **`while(myChar == '-')`** *Is `true`, continue `while` loop*
    - ***... repeated ad infinitum ...***

Because of your while loop, it never actually goes to the next character when it hits '-'. Instead, use a `break` statement:

```
foreach (char myChar in monthYear)
{
    whichMonth = whichMonth + myChar;

    if(myChar == '-') break;
}
```

Comment: That's strange.
When I placed a messagebox inside the do...while loop telling me the value of whichMonth it gave :
M
Ma
May
May-
May--
May---
and so on.

Comment: @WaqasAli: Exactly. When it hits `'-'`, it will always remain in your `while` loop because the `foreach` loop never has the chance to advance its internal pointer to the next character. If you absolutely do not want the `'-'` character in your final string, move the `break` statement to the start of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Cedric's answer, this continues forever because you are never actually changing the value of `myChar` inside of your do..while loop.  Instead what you want to do is exit your `foreach` using the `break` keyword when the `myChar` changes.

Additionally I would do:

```
if(myChar == '-')
   break;
```

No sense in calling `.ToString()` and converting the char to a string when you can just compare it to the char you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

In you `do ... while` loop, `myChar` is never modified. Just use a condition with a `break` to get out the loop.

```
foreach (char myChar in monthYear)
{
    whichMonth = whichMonth + myChar;

    if(myChar == '-')  // myChar.ToString() is not necessary, you can check the char directly (use '' to specify a char)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if your myChar is equals to "-" it will be executed always

```
whichMonth = whichMonth + myChar;
```

You are not updating myChar in the do-while

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a for each loop with a while loop inside.

foreach will iterate over all characters in your string.

lets assume 123-456

in the first iteration your `myChar` will have the value 1.

then your while loop will test if `myChar` is equal to "-". But it will never get a new value. It will be 1 forever.